# Randomly selects an item from one of the two lists

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am working with generating Random items from either one or another list. I am kind of struggling how to do that.

Basically I have two lists:

```
List<string> names = new List<string>();
List<string> surnames = new List<string>();
```

I know how to get an item from one list randomly, but I am struggling how to do so there will be a possibility of taking an item from either names or surnames.

I know there is possibly an easy solution for that but couldn't find it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *I know how to get an item from one list randomly* So can you show the relevant code of this?

Comment: If there are 4 names and 8 surnames, what do you mean by "random" in that context? Does that mean 66% of the time you will choose a surname and 33% of the time you will choose a name, for example?

Comment: No, there will always be the same amount of names and surnames, so if there are 4 names, there going to be 4 surnames as well.

Comment: Do you want there to be a 50/50 chance of getting a name or a surname, or do you want the chance to be relative to the number of each category of names? Meanning, if you have 10 times the number of surnames, do you want to have 10 times the chance of drawing a surname, or do you still want 50/50 names/surnames?

Comment: Also, given the knowledge you have, if you stuff those lists into a new list.......

Comment: You picked the only answer that **contradicts** the question. The question asks for data "from *either* names or surnames", while the answer gives you data "from *both* names and surnames." Ironically, all downvoted answers do answer your question as stated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merge two lists and access random element as follows,

```
var newList = names.Concat(surnames).ToList();
Random r = new Random();
string rand = newList[r.Next(newList.Count)];
```

Answer (score 3):

> I know how to get an item from one list randomly

Leverage the technique for taking a random item from a single list to build a simple approach that works with two lists.

- Imagine that you have a list of length `N = names.Count + surnames.Count`
- Pick a random position `p` between 0, inclusive, and `N`, exclusive
- If the position `p` is less than `names.Count`, use `names[p]`
- Otherwise, use `surnames[p - names.Length]`

Effectively, the above approach picks an item form a merged list without performing an actual merge.

**Edit:** It turns out that you wanted a random combination of `names[]` and `surnames[]`. This is a simpler task, which is achieved by picking a random element from an array twice - once from `names[]`, and then separately from `surnames[]`.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job:

```
Random r = new Random();
Int32 nameIdx = r.Next(names.Count);
Int32 surnameIdx = r.Next(surnames.Count);

String randFullname = names[nameIdx] + " " + surnames[surnameIdx];
```

This is just an example to show you how to work with random array accesses. If you need to select only one name or one surname (the question was not really clear on that point *"but I am struggling how to do so there will be a possibility of taking an item from either names or surnames"*), just throw another random [0 1] and pick the first or the second list basing your choice on the output value:

```
List<String> currentList;
String result;

Random r = new Random();

if (rand.Next(0, 2) == 0)
    currentList = names;
else
    currentList = surnames;

Int32 idx = r.Next(currentList.Count);
String result = currentList[idx];
```

Otherwise, just pick a single random entry from a concatenation:

```
List<String> con = names.Concat(surnames).ToList();
```

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: It's fine, the first attempt was wrong but now this should do exactly what OP is looking for!

Comment: Thanks and sorry I didn't make the question clear but this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do it in a one-liner you could try the following:

```
var r = new Random();
var randomName = names.Concat(surnames).OrderBy(n => r.Next()).First();
```

It's not very efficient memory wise, but it should work.